# Интерпретация арифметического оператора ^ из js в php. И что вообще это такое?

Tags: php, javascript, битовые-операции, операторы

Например `3^3`.
Что это значит и как реализовать в `PHP` подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` - Побитовое исключающее ИЛИ (XOR).
Они [побитовые операторы] идентичны (по большому счёту) и в [`JS`](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators), и в [`PHP`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: что значит побитовые? что из себя представляют?

Comment: Почитайте статьи в ответе - много интересного найдёте, в двух словах не опишешь.

Comment: ладно, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Это побитовый оператор исключающее ИЛИ XOR, он оперирует битами числа. Проще всего понять смысл побитовых операторов, если перевести десятичные числа в двоичную форму. Например, десятичная цифра 3 в двоичной форме это 11. А 2 это - 10. Вот так действует побитовое AND И (оператор `&`)

```
3 & 2 = 2
11 (3)
10 (2)
10 (2)
```

1 и 1 дает 1, 1 и 0 дает 0, 0 и 0 дает 0. Следующим образом действует OR ИЛИ (оператор `|`)

```
3 | 2 = 3
11 (3)
10 (2)
11 (3)
```

1 и 1 дает 1, 1 и 0 дает 1, 0 и 0 дает 0. Исключающее ИЛИ XOR (оператор `^`) действует следующим образом

```
3 ^ 2 = 1
11 (3)
10 (2)
01 (1)
```

1 и 1 дает 0, 1 и 0 дает 1, 0 и 0 дает 0.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Только Вы уверены что нужно оставить выводы "как работает" автору и тем, кто будет это потом читать? Где объяснение **как** именно модифицируют операторы биты? Раз уж взялись за гуж...

Comment: `0^0=0`, а не один, один - только если аргументы отличаются, если совпадают - 0

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечание, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Символ `^` обычно в выражениях имеет два значения - `xor` или степень.
[xor побитовый](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php) записывается так `3 ^ 3`. А степень записывается так `pow(3,3)`.

Comment: В `JS` в степень можно так возводить: `3 ** 3`, `^` только биты меняет.

Comment: символ крышки возводит в степень в экселе. И где то ещё я это видел.

Comment: Да везде, где нужно написать возведение в степень, а блокнот не позволяет. Это слегка путает, однажды в примере перепутал.

Comment: @Other, а где в JS _в степень можно так возводить: `3 ** 3`_?

Comment: @Grundy, http://frontender.info/exponentiation-operator/ ?

Comment: @Other, в стандарте об этом пока [ничего нет](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators), хотя да, [есть в 7 редакции](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-exp-operator)

Comment: @Grundy, Когда-то и о `let` ничего не было.